# Is it possible to run "pm create-user Name" command programmatically?

Tags: android

I am able to create the multiple user profile on Jellybean using "pm create-user Name"  terminal command on Emulator, but I want to know is there any way so I can run the same command programmatically. I don’t want to open the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the Multiple User feature was first found in 4.1, I wrote an app to do just this. I've open sourced it [here](https://github.com/RaghavSood/UserManagement). You can find the code for running that command programmatically in TerminalUtils, but I'll put it in the answer as well.

```
public static void createUser(String name)
{
    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());  

        os.writeBytes("pm create-user \"" + name + "\"\n");
        os.writeBytes("exit\n");
        os.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

TerminalUtils also contains methods to remove and rename users.

Comment: When i implement this method i got the execption java.io.IOException: write failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe) while i added all the permission which you are included into your manifest file

Comment: @Pravin008 Is your device and your app rooted?

Comment: yes the emulator is rooted so i can create the other profile using terminal but, dont know about the app root?

Comment: @Pravin008 Most likely, the app cannot get root access. Try running on a 4.1 device instead after rooting it.

Comment: As of now am only able to create the multiuser on Android Jellybean phone<not a tablet,4.2.2 emulator having some issues> but only using the shell command the details is as follows:
pm get-max-users ====>It will gives the current no of user count on device;setprop fw.max_users 3====> It will set the max number of user for you, in this case its 3;pm create-user USER_NAME====>It will create new user profile for you on device;am switch-user USER_ID====>Now you can switch to the new user And need help how to do the same thing using coding and which file I have to look/modify in Android framework.

Comment: Thanks for your support Raghav, your source code is working perfectly on Android 4.2.2 <on tablet only>.

Comment: @RaghavSood As by default application data is not sharable to another instance of same app. But when it requires to share the data, how can we do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can by :
Using [Stericson RootTools](https://code.google.com/p/roottools/) :

> RootTools provides rooted developers a standardized set of tools for
>   use in the development of rooted applications. In the end, we will
>   accomplish this by providing developers with robust, easy-to-use
>   libraries that will drastically improve development times as well as
>   promote code reuse. This project is open to any proven developer that
>   feels they have something to contribute. By pitching in together we
>   can streamline our own processes, improve the effectiveness of our
>   apps, learn new techniques, and provide a better experience for our
>   users.

Using [Android Runtime](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) :

> Allows Java applications to interface with the environment in which
>   they are running. Applications can not create an instance of this
>   class, but they can get a singleton instance by invoking getRuntime().